# The term for an object as a function parameter in ES6

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm not sure what I'm looking at here.  I'm learning TypeScript and React at the same time, and I've come across a JavaScript snippet that defines a function that accepts an object as the parameter.   I'm converting the JS to TSX. My TypeScript linter flags it as an implicit `any` type and I'd like to correct it; however, I need to understand this syntax first.  I imagine this is an ES6 thing, but I don't even know the term for it to learn more:

```
import * as React from "react";

export default function Layout({ children }) {
  return (
     <div>
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Logically, React will expand the `{children}` object, but I'd like to learn more about this syntax.  What is this called?

Comment: `Dectructuring` syntax.

Comment: Destructured function arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for [Destructuring](https://simonsmith.io/destructuring-objects-as-function-parameters-in-es6/) in ES6/ES2015